# Calculating P(x | Ck) for Naive Bayes Classifier

Tags: machine-learning, probability, naive-bayes

I understand the theory behind Bayes Theorem and the theory behind the Naive Bayes Classifier but I am having a hard time understanding the specific implementations described at https://nicolovaligi.com/naive-bayes-tensorflow.html and https://www.kaggle.com/sklasfeld/tensorflow-naive-bayes-classifier/notebook

My understanding is that p(x | Ck) means "The probability that a paragraph will contain word `x` given that it belongs to class `k`". To calculate the p(x | Ck), the authors do the following:

1. Take all paragraphs associated with a class
2. Convert each paragraph into a vector of numbers (e.g. using the tensorflow universal sentence encoder)
3. Calculate the mean, variance of the vectors (paragraphs) associated with each class.

This provides a continuous probability density function (PDF), which is nice, but I am expecting them to do the following instead:

1. Create a set of all words across the training data, across all classes.
2. Iterate over the paragraphs of each class. For each word found in step 1, record a value of `1` if the paragraph contains the word; otherwise, record a value of `0`.
3. Use the aforementioned sum to generate a discrete P(x | Ck) per word.

Obviously it is nicer to have a single continuous PDF than multiple discrete probabilities per word but this sounds more correct to me.

I have two questions:

1. Is the authors' approach an acceptable way to calculate P(x | Ck)? If so, why?
2. Is my approach an acceptable way to calculate P(x | Ck)? Can we do better?